# How to use different pages view on one url?

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

For example:
I have an url like /content/supercontenturl/.
If this content type is a video (param in my DB), I'll show videoplayer on the page and other components, but if type of content is text or other, I'd like to load specific page.vue for this content with own components, but the url must be same - /content/supercontenturl/

My structure pages:

```
index.vue
    /content/
        /_supercontenturl/
        _id.vue // The page for video 
        _id_text.vue // The page for text
        ...          // Other pages 
    index.vue
```

Comment: i don't know in `nuxt.js` if there's a solution for that, but did you try to set a component who make the control and display needed page ?

Comment: Thank you for advice! I know about this solution, but maybe exist the solution with pages.

Comment: @ELAlamiAnas Well, I guess the components are a best solution in this case.

Comment: Cool, good to know, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you should remember in nuxt all vue files inside Pages directory are components [check the guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views), and each file or directory you add there will create routes.

the easy way to succeed your demand is put the video page and content page with a proper name in components directory. Create a new file in pages it will contains in scripts the data call and template will contains the component selector, you can use a v-if or [dinamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for load the right component. and pass the data by props.